# I'm using a nested while loop to Parse a text file with multiple lines but for some reason, it only goes through the first line and I don't know why

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm using a nested while loop to Parse a text file with multiple lines but for some reason, it only goes through the first line and I don't know why.

```
              string file;
              string line;
              cout << "Whats the file name?" << endl;
              cin >> file;
            
              string inputStr;
              string buf; // Have a buffer string
              stringstream s; // create the string stream
              int field = 0;
              string input; //string for the input (i.e. name, ID, etc.)
            
              ifstream InFile(file.c_str());
              if (InFile.is_open()) {
                cout << "File found" << endl;
            
                while (getline(InFile, line)) {
                  cout << line << endl;
                  inputStr = line;
                  s << inputStr; //put the line into the stream
                  while (getline(s, input, ' ')) { //gets a string from the stream up the next comma 
                    field++;
                    cout << " field" << field << " is " << input << endl;
                  }
                  cout << "DONE" << endl;
            
                }
```

Comment: Now seems like a very good time to learn how to use a debugger, and how to use it to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Did you mean `','` instead of `' '`at `while (getline(s, input, ' ')) { //gets a string from the stream up the next comma`?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them (like including a sample of the input file).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62523114/434551

Comment: And you might want to think about `field` and its values. Is it supposed to be ever increasing, even across lines?

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare your variables when you need to use them.
2. You say `while (getline(s, input, ' ')) { //gets a string from the stream up the next comma` but then you give the third argument `' '`(a space). This should be a comma, I guess?

Fixed code:

```
        cout << "File found" << endl;

        while (getline(InFile, line)) {
            cout << line << endl;

            stringstream s(line); // create the string stream and init with line
            while (getline(s, input, ',')) { //gets a string from the stream up the next comma 
                field++;
                cout << " field" << field << " is " << input << endl;
            }
            cout << "DONE" << endl;
        }
    }
```